# Compiling multiple source file with arm-ulinucxeabi-gcc including -o -c option

Tags: compiling, make

I am compiling multiple c source which depend on multiple header files.

#### Makefile

```
SHELL=cpp2             
SOAPC=/home/amarayya/doc/../linux-lpc-1.9.0/linux-cortexm-1.9.0/projects/solus_test/app/std2.c
LDFLAGS        := -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -L $(INSTALL_ROOT)/A2F/root/usr/lib
CFLAGS        := -Os -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -I$(INSTALL_ROOT)/A2F/root/usr/include
CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE_APPS)gcc
LIBS=
COFLAGS=-O2
CWFLAGS=-Wall
CIFLAGS=
CMFLAGS=
 
out: calc.o spC.o Client.o std2.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SHELL) -o out calc.o spC.o Client.o std2.o $(LIBS)

calc.o    : calc.c spH.h 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c calc.c spH.h $(LIBS)

spC.o    : spC.c soapH.h stdsoap2.h 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c spC.c stdsoap2.h $(LIBS)

Client.o    : Client.c 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c Client.c $(LIBS)

std2.o    : std2.c
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c stdsoap2.c $(LIBS)

OBJS= calc.o spC.o Client.o std2.o

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(SHELL) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)


clean:
    -rm -f $(OBJS) *.gdb *.o
```

I am getting an the error like this:

```
Critical error: Cannot open file "arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -L/home/am./../../linux-lpc-1.9.0/linux-cortexm-1.9.0/A2F/root/usr/include -c calc.c spH.h " for reading
```

I have tried multiple ways but no result.

How can I fix this error?

Is there any problem with compiling multiple source file with `arm-ulinucxeabi-gcc -o -c`, including options?

For example:

```
arm-ulinucxeabi-gcc -c -o a a.c b.c c.c d.c
```

When I used like this I get the above error. Please guide me to solve this.

Comment: I rewrote my answer to reflect something Mat noticed.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `make` with that makefile, the default target is `out`, and the first prerequisite is `calc.o`, which the build line for that target is what is in your error.

What appears to be happening is that the entire build line is being executed by the shell as if quoted -- which it isn't, and a normal `sh` will not do that.

But you perhaps are not using something which qualifies as `sh` compatible:

```
SHELL=cpp2
```

Redefining this (it's already defined in the environment) means `cpp2` is being used, and evidently it does not behave properly.

Comment: @Mat: Looking at that makefile, I just cannot see how there is a quoting issue -- there's nothing wrong with it.  But I agree it *looks* like a quoting issue.

Comment: Sure, but is that relevant in this case?  I'm presuming the failed command is just `make`, because the line in the error is the build line for calc.o, which is the first prereq of the default target "out", so that weird $SHELL variable hasn't been used at that point.

Comment: *AH!!* Well that explains that then...

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely `SHELL=cpp2` that's causing the problem. Make runs `cpp2` with the arguments `-c` and `arm-uclinuxeabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -L/home/am./../../linux-lpc-1.9.0/linux-cortexm-1.9.0/A2F/root/usr/include -c calc.c spH.h ` and `cpp2`, whatever it is, evidently interprets this last argument as a file name.

Comment: out or calc.o is not the issue even when it is out.o also i'm facing the same error. and recently i found this error is due to use of -c and -o both option together arm-uclinuxaebi-gcc. by using the both option together ill get 3files .gdb and Fatfile and .o file.\

Comment: this are required for my project to run successfully on target so plz tell me how can i achieve this ..?

Comment: Get rid of all references to and definitions of `$SHELL` and try it.  If you cannot do that, then you may have to contact whoever is responsible for `cpp2` -- not even the internet appears to have heard of such a shell, so asking a general audience for help with it probably won't turn up much.

Comment: its not cpp2,it is SHELL=sopacpp2 that is used for creating web service application here I just gave an example Makefile. for to ask my actual question..?Is there any problem with compiling multiple source file with arm-ulinucxeabi-gcc -o -c, including options?

For example:

arm-ulinucxeabi-gcc -c -o a a.c b.c c.c d.c help me with this..?

Comment: @user34402 : If that was your question then that is the question you should have asked.  I've given you an opinion as to what is wrong in your makefile, and I'm sticking to it.  If you think *I am wrong* and you are the expert, I can't help you any further. Good luck.

Comment: I didn't said that i am an expert, if i am an expert how come i'll be asking this question over here.Please understand my question and give me a solution if you knew.and i have clearly mentioned my question as tag of this msg.

Comment: I've explained the problem which is causing the error you reported.  Note that Mat and Gilles seem to have the same opinion. It is nothing to do with the compiler, or the options you pass to the compiler, because *those options are never passed to the compiler*.  That error is *from your shell*. Not the compiler.  The reason for that is because you have redefined $SHELL.  That is your problem.  There is no other problem.